# Trouble with a SQL query (differential sum)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MA_CustSupp.CompanyName, MA_CustSupp.TaxIdNumber, SUM(MA_SaleDocSummary.GoodsAmount) AS somma, SUM(MA_SaleDocSummary.ShippingCharges) 
AS ship, MA_CustSupp.CustSupp, MA_CustSupp.FiscalCode, COUNT(MA_SaleDoc.DocumentType) AS conto, MA_CustSuppCustomerOptions.Category
FROM  MA_CustSuppCustomerOptions INNER JOIN
                         MA_CustSupp ON MA_CustSuppCustomerOptions.Customer = MA_CustSupp.CustSupp INNER JOIN
                         MA_SaleDoc INNER JOIN
                         MA_SaleDocSummary ON MA_SaleDoc.SaleDocId = MA_SaleDocSummary.SaleDocId ON MA_CustSupp.CustSupp = MA_SaleDoc.CustSupp
WHERE        (MA_SaleDoc.IncludedInTurnover = 1) AND (MA_SaleDoc.CustSuppType = 3211264) AND (MA_SaleDoc.DocumentDate >= CONVERT(DATETIME, 
                         '2014-04-01 00:00:00', 102)) AND (MA_SaleDoc.DocumentDate <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-04-08 00:00:00', 102)) AND (MA_CustSupp.CustSupp <> '022428')
GROUP BY MA_CustSupp.CompanyName, MA_CustSupp.CustSupp, MA_CustSupp.TaxIdNumber, MA_CustSupp.FiscalCode, MA_SaleDoc.DocumentType, 
                         MA_CustSuppCustomerOptions.Category
HAVING        (MA_CustSuppCustomerOptions.Category = '06') OR
                         (MA_CustSuppCustomerOptions.Category = '07')
ORDER BY somma DESC
```

Where I have the SUM of `MA_SaleDocSummary.GoodsAmount` and the COUNT of `MA_SaleDoc.DocumentType`. But I have a problem... if the `MA_SaleDoc.DocumentType` is `='3407876'` the GoodsAmount must be subtracted to the total. How can I implement in this query this variation?

Comment: What about the count? Should that exclude the concerned records too?

Comment: I think that records are not important. I need only to make a subtracion in the GoodsAmount when tht DocumentType is ='3407876'.

Comment: Also, can you please clarify if you are using MySQL or SQL Server (T-SQL)?

Comment: It's to count as subtraction. So, I changed 0 with (Amount*-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to **subtract** the amount if `DocumentType` is `3407876` then probably this will work for SQL Server

```
SUM(CASE WHEN MA_SaleDoc.DocumentType = '3407876' THEN (MA_SaleDocSummary.GoodsAmount * -1) ELSE MA_SaleDocSummary.GoodsAmount END)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SUM(if(MA_SaleDoc.DocumentType ='3407876',0,MA_SaleDocSummary.GoodsAmount))
```

That's for MySQL

Comment: Yes, you right. I make a mistake before. Unfortunally is for SQL server with PHP...